# Getting the IP Address of client connected over Terminal Services Gateway

Tags: terminal-services-gateway

I'm trying to get the external IP Address of clients connected over Terminal Services through a Terminal Services Gateway.

I can get the IP Address using WTSQuerySessionInformation if I'm not connected through the gateway, but I get nothing but 0's when I run the same app through the gateway.

Comment: Should this be on Server Fault?

Comment: I think its a programming question. But I agree there's overlap.